# SerializationException when using WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm getting SerializationException when trying to return a list via WebApi get.

[Full error message on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/sDD0XdZf)

Here's my code:

HomeController.cs:

```
public IEnumerable<Article> Get() {
    return repo.GetArticles();
}
```

Repository.cs:

```
public List<Article> GetArticles() {
    using (var db = new ArticlesContext()) {
        return db.Articles.ToList();
    }
}
```

ArticlesContext.cs:

```
public class Article {
    [Key]
    public int ArticleID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserID")]
    public virtual User Author { get; set; }
}

public class User {
    [Key]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ArticleID")]
    public virtual List<Article> Articles { get; set; }
}

public class ArticlesContext : DbContext {
    public DbSet<Article> Articles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    public ArticlesContext() : base("name=conn") {
        //etc
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any additional details regarding your SerializationException?

Answer (score 1):

Most serialization issues generally stem from either existing circular references that are being pulled or issues related to formatting (i.e. `JSON`, `XML`, etc.).

You can check if properties like Proxy Generation and Lazy Loading are enabled and disable them to try to resolve the issue within the constructor for your `DbContext`:

```
 this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
 this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

You can try adding the following section within your `Global.asax` file to handle circular references :

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
```

and the other to explicitly ignore XML serialization :

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Remove(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

Comment: Looks like you beat me to it with a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

What about returning a List instead of IEnumerable

```
public List<Article> Get() {
    return repo.GetArticles();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message it appears that there is a problem serializing the proxy class. You could try turning off proxy generation.

> Sometimes it is useful to prevent the Entity Framework from creating
>   proxy instances. For example, serializing non-proxy instances is
>   considerably easier than serializing proxy instances. Proxy creation
>   can be turned off by clearing the ProxyCreationEnabled flag. One place
>   you could do this is in the constructor of your context. For example:

```
public class BloggingContext : DbContext 
{ 
    public BloggingContext() 
    { 
        this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false; 
    }  

    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; } 
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; } 
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592886.aspx

Answer (score 0):

use `AsEnumerable()` instead `ToList()`

```
public IEnumerable<Article> GetArticles() {
    using (var db = new ArticlesContext()) {
        return db.Articles.AsEnumerable();
    }
}
```